# Applying sed in bash variable and assigning it to another

Tags: bash, sed

I have:

```
MY_FOLDER=`jq '.results_folder' ./conf.json`

FOLDER_WITHOUT_QUOTES=$MY_FOLDER | sed 's/"//g'

python my_code.py > $FOLDER_WITHOUT_QUOTES/log.log
```

So, there is a `json` file with a folder name. But `jsons` demand `strings` to be inside `"`. And reading the json with bash returns me `"`, which I want to remove

Passing it to a variable and then applying `sed` isn't working. What's the correct syntax for doing it?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use `jq -r` for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posix shell would need:

```
FOLDER_WITHOUT_QUOTES="$(printf '%s\n' "$MY_FOLDER" | sed 's/"//g')"
```

With Bash you can use the here-document syntax:

```
FOLDER_WITHOUT_QUOTES=$(sed 's/"//g' <<< "$MY_FOLDER")
```

... and you can even get rid off a call to `sed` with the special substitution:

```
FOLDER_WITHOUT_QUOTES=${MY_FOLDER//\"}
```

Note: prefer the `$(command)` syntax to the backquotes which are less readable and cannot be nested as easily.

Comment: @oguzismail Thanks. I meant Posix. Answer updated.